# Remove some elements from serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, serializearray

this is my serializeArray.I want get only these 2 push attributes only.other elements in form don't necessary.  how to remove others and only keeps these two push values(Attributes and Actions)

```
 var a = this.serializeArray();
                a.push({name: "Attributes", value:RuleConfigs.attributeContainers});
                a.push({name: "Actions", value:RuleConfigs.actionsContainers});
                $.each(a, function() {
                    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                        if (!o[this.name].push) {
                            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                        }
                        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                    } else {
                        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                    }
                });
                return o;
            };
```

this is where I call it.

```
var option=$('form').serializearray();
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: my form has many fields ex-: name,address,attributes,actions likewise. I want to keep these attributes and actions values in json array. but I don't need name and address. how can I remove name and address from that array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may looking for this

```
 var result =[];
 a.map(function(item){
     if(item.Name = 'Attribute' ||  item.Name = 'Actions' ) 
         result.push(item);
 })
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: I want add this both attribute and actions

Comment: this is attribute array format      [{"name":"Registration","value":"registration","uuid":"b17eaa29-ed48-6cfb-6ff6-f7cf0b5c2968"}]